# Plivo Rent a number Api not Working for me

Tags: php, plivo

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestAPI;

$auth_id = "My AUTH_ID";
$auth_token = "My AUTH_TOKEN";

$p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
$params = array(
        'number' => '12512077502' # Phone number to buy
    );
$response = $p->get_number($params);
print_r ($response);
```

It Will Give me Error Message

```
Array ( 
    [status] => 404 
    [response] => Array ( 
          [api_id] => 0b6214ee-aec4-11e5-ae4f-22000ac69a0d 
          [error] => not found 
 ) )
```

See here https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/phone-number-api/#rent-a-number

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the wrong function (get_number) from the python helper library. The correct one is "buy_phone_number" function which uses PhoneNumber API.

Reference - https://github.com/plivo/plivo-python/blob/master/plivo.py#L175

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Python plivo module and had the same problem.

From Plivo Support: "Use the new API:  https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/number/phonenumber/#buy-number "

What I found that the the plivo module uses the wrong URL when renting a phone number. My work around is to make the call *without* the helper library. The following is Python code but it might help give you an idea what to do.

```
import requests

params = {
        'number' : phone_number # Phone number to buy
        }

host = 'https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/%s/PhoneNumber/%s/' % \
       (account_sid, phone_number)

r = requests.post(host, timeout=5, json=params, auth=(account_sid, auth_token))
assert r.status_code == 201, 'r.status_code=%s' % `r.status_code`
```

Update: The above might not be necessary after all. I just got an update from Plivo support. The new method name is `buy_phone_number()` instead of `get_number()`. That solved the problem for me. I assume the same is true for the PHP library.